Xcode can't find node modules after upgrading to react-native 0.74
I'm attempting to upgrade from react-native 0.69 to 0.74 and while doing so when I build with Xcode I get the issue that it cannot find my node_modules folder:
error Unable to resolve module moment from /Users/xx/apps/xxx/index.js: moment could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ../../node_modules

Nothing in the setup for node_modules etc seems to have changed as part of the upgrade. If I remove e.g. moment from the app it just fails on the next dependency instead, It's not an issue with the installation of node_modules themselves and I have run yarn install, etc.
I have attempted setting the rootPath in the metro config for the project to the explicit folder but that makes metro fail on the sha1 for index.js instead.
Any suggestions on what might cause Xcode not to find the node_modules folders?
